# Noun meaning "something that stays the same"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for "something that stays the same"?

Like an antonym for "a change".

Similarity? Continuity? Sounds off.

Ex:

> While ABC was a change, XYZ was a __.

> This quarter, while ABC changed, XYZ was a __.

(To mean that XYZ stayed the same)

Comment: _constant_ is the word you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [constant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constant)

> something invariable or unchanging

So you get

> While ABC was a change, XYZ was a *constant*.

Comment: Either "XYZ was a constant" or "XYZ was constant".

Answer (score -1):

"As usual" or "The same as ever"